# GKE kubernetes kube-system resources nodeAffinity

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a multi-regional testing setup on GKE k8s 1.9.4. Every cluster has:

- an ingress, configured with `kubemci`
- 3 node pools with different node labels:

  - default-pool `system` (1vCPU / 2GB RAM)
  - frontend-pool `frontend` (2vCPU / 2GB RAM)
  - backend-pool `backend` (1vCPU / 600Mb RAM)
- HPA with scaling by the custom metric

So stuff like `prometheus-operator`, `prometheus-server`, `custom-metrics-api-server` and `kube-state-metrics` attached to a node with `system` label.

Frontend and backend pod attached to nodes with `frontend` and `backend` labels respectively (single pod to a single node), see [podantiaffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity-beta-feature).

After autoscaling scales `backend` or `frontend` pods down, them nodes remains to stay, as there appear to be pods from `kube-system` namespace, i.e `heapster`. This leads to a situation when node with `frontend` / `backend` label stays alive after downscaling even there's no backend or frontend pod left on it.

The question is: how can I avoid creating `kube-system` pods on the nodes, that serving my application (if this is really sane and possible)?

Guess, I should use taints and tolerations for `backend` and `frontend` nodes, but how it can be combined with HPA and in-cluster node autoscaler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) did the trick.

Create a cluster with a default node pool (for monitoring and `kube-system`):

```
gcloud container --project "my-project-id" clusters create "app-europe" \
  --zone "europe-west1-b" --username="admin" --cluster-version "1.9.4-gke.1" --machine-type "custom-2-4096" \
  --image-type "COS" --disk-size "10" --num-nodes "1" --network "default" --enable-cloud-logging --enable-cloud-monitoring \
  --maintenance-window "01:00" --node-labels=region=europe-west1,role=system
```

Create node pool for your application:

```
gcloud container --project "my-project-id" node-pools create "frontend" \
      --cluster "app-europe" --zone "europe-west1-b" --machine-type "custom-2-2048" --image-type "COS" \
      --disk-size "10" --node-labels=region=europe-west1,role=frontend \
      --node-taints app=frontend:NoSchedule \
      --enable-autoscaling --num-nodes "1" --min-nodes="1" --max-nodes="3"
```

then add `nodeAffinity` and `tolerations` sections to a pods template `spec` in your deployment manifest:

```
  tolerations:
  - key: "app"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "frontend"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type
            operator: In
            values:
            - custom-2-2048
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: role
            operator: In
            values:
            - frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend to check is that the amount of requested resources you have in PodSpec is enough to carry the load and that there is enough resources on system nodes to schedule all system pods.

You may try to prevent scheduling system pods to frontend or backend autoscaled nodes using either more simple `nodeSelector` or more flexible `Node Affinity`.

You can find good explanation and examples in document “[Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/)”

`Taints and Toleration` features are similar to `Node Affinity`, but more from node perspective. They allow a *node* to *repel* a set of pods. Check the document “[Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)” if you choose this way.

When you create node pool for autoscaling you can add `labels` and `taints`, so they will apply to nodes when Cluster Autoscaler (CA) upscale the pool.

In addition to restricting `system` pods from scheduling on `frontend`/`backend` nodes it would be a good idea to [configure](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) `PodDisruptionBudget` and autoscaler `safe-to-evict` option for pods that could prevent CA from removing a node during downscale.

According to [Cluster Autoscaler FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md) there are several types of pods that may prevent CA to downscale your cluster:

- Pods with restrictive PodDisruptionBudget (PDB).
- Kube-system pods that:

  - are not run on the node by default,
  - don't have PDB or their PDB is too restrictive (since CA 0.6).
- Pods that are not backed by a controller object (so not created by deployment, replica set, job, stateful set etc).
- Pods with local storage. *
- Pods that cannot be moved elsewhere due to various constraints (lack of resources, non-matching node selectors or affinity, matching anti-affinity, etc)

*Unless the pod has the following annotation (supported in CA 1.0.3 or later):

```
"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true"
```

Prior to version 0.6, Cluster Autoscaler was not touching nodes that were running important kube-system pods like DNS, Heapster, Dashboard etc. 
If these pods landed on different nodes, CA could not scale the cluster down and the user could end up with a completely empty 3 node cluster. 
In 0.6, was added an option to tell CA that some system pods can be moved around. If the user configures a [PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) for the kube-system pod, then the default strategy of not touching the node running this pod is overridden with PDB settings. 
So, to enable kube-system pods migration, one should set minAvailable to 0 (or <= N if there are N+1 pod replicas.) 
See also [I have a couple of nodes with low utilization, but they are not scaled down. Why?](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#i-have-a-couple-of-nodes-with-low-utilization-but-they-are-not-scaled-down-why)

[Cluster Autoscaler FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#which-version-on-cluster-autoscaler-should-i-use-in-my-cluster) can help you choose correct version for you cluster.

To have better understanding of what is laying under the hood of Cluster Autoscaler check the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler)

Comment: As for the question, it's more convenient for me to use taints, since I don't need to edit resources at `kube-system` namespace, which is undesirable. It's easy to use and pretty straightforward.